# custom docker image containing nanoiis and sqlcmd utility

Tags: image, containers, sqlcmd, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I would like to create an image containing **nanoiis** image with the **sqlcmd utility** installed. I could further use this custom image in our `DevOps pipeline`.

The sqlcmd is available at [this sqlcmd link] from the microsoft website 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017.

I'm kind of stuck because the utility is in a msi file (`MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi`) and I don't know how to run a software that would popup an UI unlike `SQLserver` that can be installed from command line.

Once done, I can commit the image and use it in our pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things:

1. Nano server does not support IIS role anymore
2. You can not install MSI files on nano server either

You need to base your image off windowsservercore instead and run your installation in quiet mode to avoid popups in MSI file.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is it documented anywhere that Nanoserver does not support IIS role anymore?

Comment: Here is details about changes to nanoserver (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/nano-in-semi-annual-channel). You can see if you go to IIS docker hub image that there is no more new images published based on nanoserver as a result